# C# Format Exception (double to string)

Tags: c#

I apologize if this seems to be a duplicate, but none of the answers I have found have solved my problem.

I have the following calculation:

```
 double NewTotal = 12.0 * (SumCopay + Premium);
```

SumCoPay and Premium are also doubles.

I am trying to format the output like this:

```
 string.Format("{0:0.00}" , NewTotal.ToString())
```

But I am getting a "Input String was not in a correct format" error.

The troubleshooting tip begins by saying: "When converting a string to DateTime..."

So I am guessing that it thinks that my value is a date.

The value of NewTotal I am currently dealing with is 1100.4

I have also tried:

```
 NewTotal.ToString("N2")
```

but I got the same error.

Comment: By the way...If I just output NewTotal.ToString(), I am getting the same error.  I think it may be something else, such as the gridview cell I am trying to place the value into may be looking for an integer instead of a double.

Comment: If that's the case, then you haven't provided enough code.

Comment: There would be no code to provide, since it is a property of a control.  I didn't provide enough explanation.

Comment: You could post your GridView code. Even generated code or screenshots would help.

Answer (score 1):

The formatter you're using in your `string.Format` does not apply to `string`s, but you're converting your `double` to a `string` before it's being formatted. If you simply remove the `.ToString()` from your `NewTotal` variable, it will work.

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}" , NewTotal);
```

EDIT: I just fired this code up in VS2012, and it works perfectly:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double SumCopay = 3.45;
            double Premium = 2.34;
            double NewTotal = 12.0 * (SumCopay + Premium);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", NewTotal);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the same in Linqpad. Works fine for me.

Comment: It wasn't the syntax, it was that the gridview cell I was trying to place the value into was expecting an int.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are feeding `string.Format` a string, not a double.

I think removing `.ToString()` from `NewTotal.ToString()` will fix your problem.

Comment: It should work with `ToString` as well, there shouldn't be any exception.